# Openstack Dashboard access after installing w\ MAAS

Tags: maas, openstack

I've installed MAAS and Openstack as guided by
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/
and
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure, however on step 5 it states:

> if you are using this to deploy OpenStack on a IaaS for testing
>   purposes, the last step is to expose the services that should be made
>   available to outside requests, opening the required firewall ports in
>   the security group. This is obviously not needed when deploying using
>   MAAS.

Quite frankly it's not obvious how this is intended to work - I don't know how to access the Openstack dashboard. I ran these commands: `juju expose openstack-dashboard` and 
`juju expose nova-cloud-controller` per the guide, however `juju status openstack-dashboard` still does not yield an address for me to go to.  I've tried hitting the ip's of my (hardware) nodes to see if it's living out there somewhere, but got nowhere.

Comment: I got it - I just didn't have enough nodes to start up the dashboard yet, it started up on the 9th node...

Comment: I guess that was only half the issue though - using the second link above, I set the admin password in a file, however it does not work on the web UI (can't log in). Thoughts? Perhaps how to reset it?

Comment: You may want to **edit your question** to incorporate information about how your situation has changed. (Click the `edit` link.)

Answer (score 2):

When Juju gives you the `public-adress: 367pb.cluster01.yourdomain.com` style address, you have at add `/horizon` onto the end of that to get to the web interface page.

All authentication is handled by keystone.  You need to ensure there is a relation between the  openstack-dashboard and keystone services. You should be able to access the dashboard (initially) using username 'admin' and the password that was set for the 'admin-password' in the keystone section of the configuration you passed to 'juju deploy'.  If you forgot to specify the configuration when deploying keystone, one was randomly generated for you by the charm.  You should be able to find this in `/var/lib/keystone/keystone.passwd` on the keystone node.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I deployed Keystone without change password but I can't find /var/lib/keystone/keystone.passwd on my keystone node. Where can I find it ? I use juju 1.23.3 
I tried tu use the Gui to change the password but when I commited the change Openstack dashboard didn't see the change ! any idea what is going on ?